# Handling error messages as exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

can we throw exception in one class and can we catch all those exceptions in a separate exception class in c#?

Now my question is when ever the values == null then we are displaying the message there itself. Now i have to use exceptions if the values are equal to null.
Can i throw the exception like

```
if(customer == null)
        throw new CustomerNullException();
if(incometype == null)
        throw new IncomeTypeNullException();
```

Now Can i handle these exceptions in a separate class??

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't throw exception as your regular flow. especially if you know where and why did it happen. in you case i would have create a class called `HandleProblems` and send the error to that class. no need to throw exception and catch it as it is more expensive then calling a method.

```
   public class Log
   {
      public static void WriteLine(string errorMsg)
      {
         string err = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") + " - " + errorMsg;

         if (File.Exists("@d:\log.txt") == false)
         {
            File.Create("@d:\log.txt");
         }

         using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("@d:\log.txt", true))
         {
            writer.WriteLine(err);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: My task is to reduce the code in that class, so that we can group all error messages in to one thing.

Comment: @user2619542 Maybe you should write some `ErrorHandler` library which does all the error handling for different cases.

Comment: Like in that class we should write error messages in a method suppose say checkcustomer() in that should i display the error message? @Mayank

Comment: Every class can have an instance of `ErrorHandler` and everytime you need to show an error, call `ErrorHandler.Error(error, errorType)`. or `ErrorHandler.Warning(warning, warningType)`

Comment: @No Idea For Name: Can you just show me a simple example like how to send error messages to a newly created class?

Comment: @user2619542 i'll edit the answer in just a minute, but it's just a static method in a class that everyone knows. i'll give you example for log

Comment: @user2619542 is it helpful?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Well i didn't understand that. I got an idea but i'm not sure whether that will work or not. 1)Creating a new method with in that class which handles all the errors or creating a new class and using a switch statement for handling errors as i have many error messgaes around 25. Can you suggest whether my idea is a good one or not?

Comment: @user2619542 usually for handling errors most projects i know create a class for handling errors and handling the errors there, maybe with a switch case, but most of them just write it to a log or to the output....

Comment: @NoIdeaForName In my case its not about using log. I should just display the error message

Comment: @user2619542 then the same method is good for you, just change it to MessageBox.Show(err);

Comment: I found a case in my project that they used throw NotfoundException(err)  ex: wat is understood how my code changes if i use this as follow : throw NotFoundException("Could not find the customer corresponding to the taxId '{0}' Current Employment will not be imported.", new TaxId(line.TaxId).Masked)); I have to make sure with my manager whether i can do like this or not

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are really bad idea for handling errors. You should rethink your error handling architecture as exceptions have huge overhead. Please read [Exceptions and Performance](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions.html) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Did you mean to say "for handling warnings"? Error handling is *exactly* what exceptions are for, but they should be reserved for exceptional errors: ones that would not be expected in normal operation, and are non-recoverable (from the perspective of the throwing class).

Comment: @StephenJ.Anderson Exceptions are for error handling but that doesn't mean one should throw an exception left and right just because there is a try/catch block waiting down the line. Exceptions should be used in moderation and are very helpful when used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should be saved only for exceptional circumstances (haw haw haw). They're extremely performance intensive because of the metadata that exceptions save and pass around, including a stack trace. As a result while they're good to have to debug, catch and handle errors that you don't expect to typically encounter (but should be prepared for, say if a parameter is passed as null that 'should' never be null), they're not great for the regular functioning of a program.

If there are special error circumstances that you expect to crop up in normal program functioning, use your own error handler class externally that you pass your desired error parameters to, or use some sort of validation. Doing something like `myCollection.pop` on an empty data structure doesn't need to throw an exception, because (for whatever reason) your program might not check whether the collection is empty. However it can do something like return Null and call your errorHandler class, to do whatever is needed when the data structure is empty.